# How to create a plot based on a grouped value in R?

Tags: r, statistics

So I have an assignment where I am supposed to create a simple plot based on some values:

```
Species         Weight    Avg Cornea Diameter
Great Grey      971       19.50
Great Grey      1209      19.00
Great Grey      1793      21.00
Snowy           1572      22.50
Snowy           1500      23.50
Snowy           1490      22.00
```

How do I create a plot of the Great Grey species only and the Snowy species only? As the assignment is supposed to be simple I'm not sure how to go back this. I want to be able to plot the Great Grey species using
`plot(Weight~CorneaAvg)` but when I do that there is data for all of the species not each individual one.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df1 = subset(df, Species == "GreatGrey")
df2 = subset(df, Species == "Snowy")

with(df1, plot(Weight ~ Avg_Cornea_Diameter))
with(df2, plot(Weight ~ Avg_Cornea_Diameter))
```

Or you can try:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  split(df$Species) %>%
  lapply(function(x){
    with(x, plot(Weight ~ Avg_Cornea_Diameter))
  })
```

**Data:**

```
df = read.table(text="Species         Weight    Avg_Cornea_Diameter
                GreatGrey      971       19.50
                GreatGrey      1209      19.00
                GreatGrey      1793      21.00
                Snowy           1572      22.50
                Snowy           1500      23.50
                Snowy           1490      22.00", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: @ASidhu Not sure about the error message, but if this answers your question, feel free to accept it:)

Comment: it turns out I had just typed something wrong but thank you again for all the help :)

Comment: @ASidhu Glad that it helped. Don't forget to accept an answer. To do that, click on the check mark beside the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this
temp[temp$species %in% c("Great Grey","Snowy")]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You might consider learning ggplot2 as you can quickly manage plotting aesthetics based on subsets of the data.

I'll give you some example code and you can see how easy it is to create different plots.

Using the df created by @useR

```
library(ggplot2)
# Separate scatterplot by Species using faceting: facet_wrap
ggplot(df, aes(x=Avg_Cornea_Diameter, y=Weight)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~Species)

# Plot both Species in same graph, but color code by Species
ggplot(df, aes(x=Avg_Cornea_Diameter, y=Weight, colour=Species)) + geom_point() 

# Set colour by Species, use facet_wrap and add scales='free' to control axis scales, set theme colours. Each of these can simply be added or removed.
ggplot(df, aes(x=Avg_Cornea_Diameter, y=Weight, colour=Species)) + geom_point() + theme_bw() + xlab("Avg Cornea Diameter")
```

Comment: I'll try tthis out next time!